# Access devices "inside" subrouter

Tags: networking, router

I have plans to buy a second router (dlink) to make a subnetwork for my DIY CCTY (using 2 IP cams and a computer to store and view the realtime image using VLC).

But i need to know if i will be able to access at least the computer with the files to copy if needed.

A image to better illustrate the imagined network structure:
[image]

Will i be able to access subdevice 1 from device 1 (green line) or i need to tweak the routers? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to tweak the routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on how you set it up.

First of all, do you really need routing? In other words, do subdev 1&2 need to be on a different subnet/network than dev1?

If no, then just put the router in switch mode and be done with it.

If yes, it gets a little more complex, and it depends on what the hardware supports. It's been so long since I've used consumer networking hardware that I don't know for sure, but I doubt the d-link, or more importantly, whatever Main Router is, supports it, but here's what you would need to do:

1. Disable NAT on Sub-Router
2. Add a static route from Router to Sub-Router for 192.168.16.0/24

Sub-Router already knows how to get to Router because of DHCP. The specific config depends on your specific hardware, and again, the hardware may not support it. If you're flexible, I recommend looking at Mikrotik. They have full routers as cheap as $20 which easily support this.

**EDIT:** I missed the part about only needing to access one device. If that's the case then you can definitely do it with a standard consumer router and just port forward to the one device.

Comment: I want to separate sub1 and 2 from 1 because they are ip cameras and they are stuttering my network

Comment: @Vico Putting them on a different subnet shouldn't help more than a dedicated switch. Where is the computer they are sending their data to?

Comment: @Vico Also they shouldn't be slowing down your network but that's a different issue.

Comment: I want to use subdev1 to record the subdev2 (ip camera). I thought keeping both camera and recorder inside a subrouter would help easing network throttle (a friend told me)

Comment: @Vico I'm sorry but your friend told you wrong. You shouldn't be having speed problems but even if you are a dedicated network is unnecessary and overkill, and will get in your way at some point. Just get a dumb switch (NOT a hub, just an unmanaged switch. Plug one port into your main router, and one into each subdev. All traffic between the subdevs will stay within the switch.

Comment: @Vico No problem.

Answer (score 2):

The "sub-router" as you call it is only used for this camera network and there is only one device on that subnet you need to access, then you could set up Port Forwarding with the just about any consumer router.  You would treat the router IP address as the device to connect to. 
But, if you need to access ANY of the devices it gets more complicated.

That's assuming the sub-router is doing NAT, which they all do by default. It could be in bridge mode, but if you are trying to keep camera traffic off of your main network, you might need your sub-router to have some firewall feature.  If it is slamming your network they may be compromised already.